# Solve in positive distinct integers the equation: $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=3(x+y+z+w).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:** Solve in positive distinct integers the equation: $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=3(x+y+z+w).$

**My Attempt:** WLOG assume that $1\leq x<y<z<w.$ Then $$4x^2<\sum_{cyc}x^2$$ and $$12x<3\sum_{cyc}x.$$ I found one solution $(1,2,3,4)$, but I can't find other solutions. I feel that one might use the above inequalities to obtain a lower bound on some variable. I also observed that if $w\geq 5$ then $$x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2>3(x+y+z+w).$$ How should I prove this if it is true?

Comment: [Here's the answer](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1351545_nt_challenge)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the possible values of $x^2-3x$. It can take a few negative values when $x$ is small and then it quickly takes larger and larger positive values when $x$ gets larger.

Since the sum of the four quantities $(x_i^2-3x_i)$ has to be zero, we can do this :
Since $x^2-3x \ge -2$ you must have $w^2-3w = -((x^2-3x)+(y^2-3y)+(z^2-3z)) \le -(-2-2-2) = 6$.

But since $x^2-3x \ge 10 > 6$ when $x \ge 5$, this implies that $w \le 4$.
Therefore the solution can only involve integers up to $4$.

Comment: I don't' understand why $x^2-3x\geq -2.$ $x^2-3x$ is negative for $0\leq x\leq 3.$ Otherwise it is positive.

Comment: $1^2-3*1 = 1-3 = -2, 2^2-3*2 = 4-6 = -2$ and then if $x \ge 3$ you have $x^2-3x \ge 3x-3x=0$ so that's it.